# DataBind Telerik treeview

Tags: linq-to-sql, data-binding, treeview, telerik

I want to bind data to telerik treeview. Do i need to make linq to sql .dbml file or it can be done directly using database file?

Answer (score 1):

it can be done directly using database file..but if you want to use linq you can even use it..